# specifying "skip NA" when calculating mean of the column in a data frame created by Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, na

I am learning `Pandas` package by replicating the outing from some of the R vignettes. Now I am using the `dplyr` package from R as an example:

http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

#### R script

```
planes <- group_by(hflights_df, TailNum)
delay <- summarise(planes,
  count = n(),
  dist = mean(Distance, na.rm = TRUE))
delay <- filter(delay, count > 20, dist < 2000)
```

#### Python script

```
planes = hflights.groupby('TailNum')
planes['Distance'].agg({'count' : 'count',
                        'dist' : 'mean'})
```

How can I state explicitly in python that `NA` needs to be skipped?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a trick question, since **you don't do that**. Pandas will automatically exclude `NaN` numbers from aggregation functions. Consider my `df`:

```
    b   c   d  e
a               
2   2   6   1  3
2   4   8 NaN  7
2   4   4   6  3
3   5 NaN   2  6
4 NaN NaN   4  1
5   6   2   1  8
7   3   2   4  7
9   6   1 NaN  1
9 NaN NaN   9  3
9   3   4   6  1
```

The internal `count()` function will ignore `NaN` values, and so will  `mean()`. The only point where we get `NaN`, is when **the only value is `NaN`**. Then, we take the mean value of an empty set, which turns out to be `NaN`:

```
In[335]: df.groupby('a').mean()
Out[333]: 
          b    c    d         e
a                              
2  3.333333  6.0  3.5  4.333333
3  5.000000  NaN  2.0  6.000000
4       NaN  NaN  4.0  1.000000
5  6.000000  2.0  1.0  8.000000
7  3.000000  2.0  4.0  7.000000
9  4.500000  2.5  7.5  1.666667
```

Aggregate functions work in the same way:

```
In[340]: df.groupby('a')['b'].agg({'foo': np.mean})
Out[338]: 
        foo
a          
2  3.333333
3  5.000000
4       NaN
5  6.000000
7  3.000000
9  4.500000
```

*Addendum*: Notice how the standard [dataframe.mean API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) will allow you to control inclusion of `NaN` values, where *the default is exclusion*.

Comment: Thanks, and how do I do the opposite: make the `pandas` include `NaN`?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś have a look at the last line, which links to the manual. It lists the option of including `NaN`. You can build on top of that as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 6):

What foobar said is true in regards to how it was implemented by default, but there is a very easy way to specify skipna. Here is an exemple that speaks for itself:

```
def custom_mean(df):
    return df.mean(skipna=False)

group.agg({"your_col_name_to_be_aggregated":custom_mean})
```

That's it! You can customize your own aggregation the way you want, and I'd expect this to be fairly efficient, but I did not dig into it.

It was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375020/408853), but I thought I'd help spread the good news!
Answer was found in the official [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).

Comment: @lokheart, this might interest you.

Comment: Why np.mean does not work?