# How can .mean() exclude NaN values inside aggregate function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataset has many columns. Here are two:

```
Index  Graduated  Age
0      College    24
1      HighSch    18
2      College    26
3      College    Nan
4      HighSch    20
```

The mean of Age is simple enough:

```
df.Age.mean()
```

However, I have many other columns, therefore I'm using agg():

```
df.groupby('Graduated').agg({'Age':'mean'})
```

The error I get:

> No numeric types to aggregate
>   If I insert a number instead of NaN, it works!!

**Does the agg() function not allow us to run the mean if column has NaN values?** Is there a way around that?

Comment: By the looks of it, it is not the "number" `nan`  but instead a string `"Nan"`. Change it to `np.nan`  from numpy and it should work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039328/specifying-skip-na-when-calculating-mean-of-the-column-in-a-data-frame-created for an answer to your particular question not including the `"Nan"` issue mentioned by @ayhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ayhan said, the `Nan` values look like strings. One possible solution is that  you can replace the `Nan` strings you have with actual `NaN` values using either of those two lines:

`df['Age'] = df['Age'].replace(r'Nan', np.nan, regex=True)`

@ayhan's suggestion is to use `to_numeric` method.

`df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce')`

Then execute the aggregation that you mentioned in your question. And I would do the same for all columns to avoid confusion and get things straight from the beginning for analysis purposes in the future.

Comment: You might still need `df["age"] = pd.to_numeric(df["age"], errors="coerce")` if the dtype is object.

Comment: I tried it and gave me, `ValueError: Unable to parse string "Nan" at position 3`

Comment: That worked, would you like me to add it to the answer?

Comment: Sure that would be nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149341/discussion-between-tiba-and-ayhan).

Comment: That worked. Thank you @ayhan. Should I be worried that I have to use errors='coerce'? would a newer version of pandas make my solution obsolete?

Comment: @AdamSchroeder before the conversion, you can execute `df['Age'][pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce').isnull()]`  and this will show you which cells are coerced to nan.