# scipy stats error in calculating standard normal in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to figure out the probability under a normal distribution in for my data `df` in python.  I'm not experienced with python or programming.  The following user-defined function I scraped from this site works, the scipy function does not work...

UDF:

```
def normal(x,mu,sigma):
    return ( 2.*np.pi*sigma**2. )**-.5 * np.exp( -.5 * (x-mu)**2. / sigma**2. )
df["normprob"] = normal(df["return"],df["meanreturn"],df["sdreturn"])
```

This scipy function does not work:

```
df["normdistprob"] = scip.norm.sf(df["return"],df["meanreturn"],df["sdreturn"])
```

and it returns the following error

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1815: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1816: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1817: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  cond1 = self._open_support_mask(x) & (scale > 0)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1818: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)
```

Any advice is appreciated.  Also to note, the first 20 cells of

```
df["meanreturn"]
```

are NA, not sure if that's affecting it.

Comment: yeah, having NA in any math calculation will make it to crash

Comment: What is your intended way of calculating the probability if the mean is NA?

Comment: Okay, I thought even though it was the first 20 cells, that wouldn't affect the rest of the dataset, and the first 20 cells of 'df["normdist"]' would simply be NaN as well.  Also, from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039328/specifying-skip-na-when-calculating-mean-of-the-column-in-a-data-frame-created, it seems that the NaN cells wouldn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the survival function is what you need. I believe what you're looking for is scipy's `pdf` function, specifically the pdf for a normal random variable. I tested it against the custom function you used.

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.6, 0.5, 0.13], 'mu': [0, 1, 1], 'std': [1, 2, 1]})
>>> norm.pdf(df['x'], df['mu'], df['std'])
array([ 0.3332246 ,  0.19333406,  0.27324443])
>>> def normal(x,mu,sigma):
...     return ( 2.*np.pi*sigma**2. )**-.5 * np.exp( -.5 * (x-mu)**2. / sigma**2. )
...
>>> normal(df['x'], df['mu'], df['std'])
0    0.333225
1    0.193334
2    0.273244
dtype: float64
```

Note that if your `mu` and `std` columns are `np.nan`, then you will get the runtime warnings, but you will still get an output, similar to the custom function.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.6, 0.5, 0.13], 'mu': [np.nan, 1, 1], 'std': [np.nan, 2, np.nan]})
>>> norm.pdf(df['x'], df['mu'], df['std'])
C:\Users\lyang3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1650: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
C:\Users\lyang3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:876: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
  return (self.a <= x) & (x <= self.b)
C:\Users\lyang3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:876: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  return (self.a <= x) & (x <= self.b)
C:\Users\lyang3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1651: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  cond1 = self._support_mask(x) & (scale > 0)
array([        nan,  0.19333406,         nan])
>>> normal(df['x'], df['mu'], df['std'])
0         NaN
1    0.193334
2         NaN
dtype: float64
```

You could avoid the warnings if you set your `np.nan` values to `None`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.6, 0.5, 0.13], 'mu': [None, 1, 1], 'std': [None, 2, None]})
>>> normal(df['x'], df['mu'], df['std'])
0         NaN
1    0.193334
2         NaN
dtype: float64
>>> norm.pdf(df['x'], df['mu'], df['std'])
array([        nan,  0.19333406,         nan])
```

Note, I would either remove rows where your `meanreturn` and `sdreturn` values are `NaN`. Otherwise, I would make the assumption that you are looking for the probability of `x` assuming a standard normal distribution, which you would then have to set the `NaN` values of `meanreturn` to 0 and `NaN` values of `sdreturn` to 1.

One last comment to add is that if all the rows of your dataframe assume a standard normal distribution for calculating the probability from the pdf, then you don't need to pass the `mu` column and `std` column. `norm.pdf` already assumes a standard normal. In this case, you can just run your code like so:

```
>>> norm.pdf(df['x'])
array([ 0.3332246 ,  0.35206533,  0.39558542])
```