# Pandas groupby with count aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to get the count of each unique value for a given column. For example, I'd like to get the following results from the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': [1,1,2,3,3,3], 'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': [6,5,4,3,2,1]})
```

What I want is a dataframe that looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': [1,2,3], 'count': [2, 1, 3]})
```

I found that I can get close to this with:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg('count')[['id', 'a']]
```

But I'm looking for a way that's a bit more descriptive of what is happening / "pythonic". Additionally, I'd have to do a column rename as well. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can look into groupby and will see many answers.Use name parameter to name grouped column,  df.groupby('id')['a'].count().reset_index(name = 'count')

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to reference some arbitrary column (such as 'a' in this example)? I'm looking for a descriptive way to perform this operation. I'll edit the original question to clarify being descriptive instead of just being "pythonic".

Comment: @David - I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53781634/2901002) - part `4. How to aggregate counts?`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael Looks like `df['id'].value_counts().sort_index().rename_axis('id').reset_index(name='count')` would closest match to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @David - Yes, I rather add link like answer, because a bit wide problematic. Be free upvote Q/A if helpful.