# How to add a column to a dataframe with statistics from a grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's consider the following DataFrame:

```
d = {'timestamp': ['2019-04-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-04-02', '2019-04-02', '2019-04-02'],\
     'type': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'],\
     'value': [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    timestamp   type    value
0   2019-04-01  A       3
1   2019-04-01  B       4
2   2019-04-02  B       4
3   2019-04-02  B       2
4   2019-04-02  A       5
```

What I would like to obtain is another column containing a metric of all the values within a particular time period and type.
For instance, the standard deviation per type per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['timestamp','type'])['value'].std().reset_index()
print (df)
    timestamp type     value
0  2019-04-01    A       NaN
1  2019-04-01    B       NaN
2  2019-04-02    A       NaN
3  2019-04-02    B  1.414214
```

If need multiple metrics is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['timestamp','type'])['value'].describe()
print (df)
                 count  mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
timestamp  type                                                
2019-04-01 A       1.0   3.0       NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
           B       1.0   4.0       NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
2019-04-02 A       1.0   5.0       NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
           B       2.0   3.0  1.414214  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0
```

More information about aggregation is in [Aggregation in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas).

---

EDIT: If need months only use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df = df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.month.rename('months'),'type'])['value'].describe()
print (df)
             count      mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
months type                                                    
4      A       2.0  4.000000  1.414214  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0
       B       3.0  3.333333  1.154701  2.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

If need years with months use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for month period:

```
m = df['timestamp'].dt.to_period('m').rename('months')
df = df.groupby([m,'type'])['value'].describe()
print (df)
              count      mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
months  type                                                    
2019-04 A       2.0  4.000000  1.414214  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0
        B       3.0  3.333333  1.154701  2.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

Comment: Could you add a possible solution to have stats per month?