# What does indexing into the result of a pandas groupby do?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   ['1', '2', '3'], 
                   ['4', '5', '6']],
                  index=['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

    x   y   z
A   a   b   c
B   1   2   3
C   4   5   6
```

I saw the code, `df.groupby('x')['y']`. In here, what does `['y']` do?  I understand `('x')`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it returns the column `y`

Comment: would you like too look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781645/8333806).
Merci

Comment: @NicolasGervais It returns `pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object`.

Comment: here,`('x')` is used for DataFrameGroupBy whereas `['y']` is used for SeriesGroupBy in pandas

Comment: `df.groupby('x')` groups on col `x` while `df.groupby('x')['y']` <- this would make a function operate on col `y` after grouping on `x` , eg `df.groupby('x')['y'].sum()` would give sum on `y` after grouping on `x` however `df.groupby('x').sum()` would return sum of all columns (not only y) after grouping on x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new index is the new group you made with `groupby()`. The `['y']` will return the column `y`. But, you also need to call a function on your aggregated rows, like `sum()`. Here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Mark', 'Laura', 'Adam', 'Roger', 'Anna'],
                   'City':['Lisbon', 'Montreal', 'Lisbon', 'Berlin', 'Glasgow'],
                   'Height':[173.4, 151.8, 179.3, 169.1, 166.4]})
print(df)
```

```
    Name      City  Height
0   Mark    Lisbon   173.4
1  Laura  Montreal   151.8
2   Adam    Lisbon   179.3
3  Roger    Berlin   169.1
4   Anna   Glasgow   166.4
```

Return the sum of the people, grouped by the `City`:

```py
df.groupby('City').sum()['Height']
```

```py
Out[46]: 
City
Berlin      169.1
Glasgow     166.4
Lisbon      352.7
Montreal    151.8
Name: Height, dtype: float64
```

The new index is the group, and you selected one column to display. You can either put it before or after `sum()`.

Comment: If you group values, you need to tell pandas how do you want them grouped. By mean? By sum? Because that's what aggregation is

Comment: @MadPhysicist Have you read the Pandas docs? It sounds like you need a tutorial or guide, Stack Overflow isn’t really meant for this. Also, I think the code you shared is already doing that.

Comment: I'm not OP. Just a heckler from the sidelines. I'll take your advice regardless.

Comment: OK. I've looked through the docs. I see nothing that indicates that you have to aggregate after grouping.

Comment: From the docs: `DataFrameGroupBy` Returns: 
Depends on the __calling object__ and returns groupby object that contains information about the groups.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oops, sorry for assuming your were OP! Indeed, I also assumed you could just get the column directly, no need to call anything. Unfortunately I’m not at my computer right now so I can’t check.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Would managing to print the output of a groupby like the one in the OP (without aggregation or a function) constitute enough proof?

Comment: `print(list(df.groupby('x')['y']))` where `df` is the one from the OP. (I see you’re in Montreal too, hi!)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile What is OP?

Comment: @jayko03 OP = original poster

Answer (score 0):

```
groupby()
```

created a group of df which allotted the same `x` values to the given rows. Then, for each of these groups, you grabbe the `y` column and counted how many times it appeared. It's like value_counts() (a shortcut to this groupby() operation).