# pandas groupby and agg getting TypeError

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I saw that it is possible to do groupby and then agg to let pandas produce a new dataframe that groups the old dataframe by the fields you specified, and then aggregate the fields you specified, on some function (sum in the example below).

However, when I wrote the following:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10, 100], ['tom', 15, 200], ['nick', 15, 150], ['juli', 14, 140]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'salary'])

# trying to groupby and agg    
grouping_vars = ['Name']    
nlg_study_grouped = df(grouping_vars,axis = 0).agg({'Name': sum}).reset_index()
```

| Name | Age | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 10 | 100 |
| tom | 15 | 200 |
| nick | 15 | 150 |
| juli | 14 | 140 |

I am expecting the output to look like this (because it is grouping by `Name` then summing the field `salary`:

| Name | salary |
| --- | --- |
| tom | 300 |
| nick | 150 |
| juli | 140 |

The code works in someone else's example, but my toy example is producing this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6fb9c0ade242> in <module>
      1 grouping_vars = ['Name']
      2 
----> 3 nlg_study_grouped = df(grouping_vars,axis = 0).agg({'Name': sum}).reset_index()

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I wonder if I missed something dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
print(df.groupby('Name').sum()['salary'])
```

To use multiple functions

```
print(df.groupby(['Name'])['salary']
         .agg([('average','mean'),('total','sum'),('product','prod')])
         .reset_index())
```

If you want to group by multiple columns, then you can try adding multiple column names within groupby list

```
Ex: df.groupby(['Name','AnotherColumn'])...
```

Further, you can refer this question
[Aggregation in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas)

Comment: What if I want to `groupby` more than just `Name`, and `agg` on functions other than `sum`?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I was trying to understand the syntax presented in my original problem with the dict notation `{Name: sum}`, but it seems I can forget about it and just use this syntax. But still a little curious why it works with some other example but not the one I created.

Comment: Better use `df.groupby('Name')['salary'].sum()`. The other way around computes all columns to just keep one