# groupby and agg with multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'List' : ['P111', 'P999', 'P111;P999;P777', 'P555', 'P666;P111;P333'],
                    'Color' : ['red', 'red', 'blue','yellow', 'red']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cod' : ['P111', 'P222', 'P333', 'P444', 'P555', 'P666', 'P777'],
                    'Animal' : ['DOG', 'CAT', 'BUG','SNAKE,DOG', 'CAT,BUG', 'DOG', 'SNAKE'],
                    'Letter' : ['A,F', 'C', 'S,M', 'F,L', 'C,A','M,C', 'Z,L']})
```

and at some point I do something like:

```
...
.groupby('index')
.agg(List=('List','first'),
     Sequence=('Sequence','first'),
     Animal=('Animal','|'.join),
     Letter=('Letter','|'.join))
...
```

This works but i would like to know if there is a way to insert into .agg() all columns of df1 with 'first' and all columns of df2 with joins.
This is because I don't always have the same number of columns, also sometimes I have names that have spaces and this prevents me from inserting them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way if you want aggregate on all columns in one go:

```
...
.astype(dict.fromkeys(df2, str))
.groupby('index')
.agg({**dict.fromkeys(df1, 'first'), **dict.fromkeys(df2, '|'.join)})
...
```

Some details:

- `dict.fromkeys(iterable, value)`: creates a new dict with keys from `iterable` and values set to `value`.
- Type casting with `.astype(dict.fromkeys(df2, str))` is required because in case some columns in `df2` are numeric type then `'|'.join` will not work.

Comment: A thousand thanks!

Comment: I am getting this error: **TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found**
and: **FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in SeriesGroupBy.agg is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .agg, select only columns which should be valid for the function.**  Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Mario, I think in your dataframe `df2` there are some columns containing floating point values, so `'|'.join` would not work because of floating point values. Can you check?

Comment: It is as you say! Is there any way to stem this problem?

Comment: Do you want to ignore floating point columns while doing join?

Comment: I can't ignore them, I need to join those too

Comment: Do you think instead of `join` you can `agg` with `list` for e.g. you can do : `**dict.fromkeys(df2, list)`

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I necessarily need a separator to distinguish values