# Merge two columns from different df and put the results in the same columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to join two dataframes columns by particular columns but I would like some columns to be joined together. I asked something similar here: [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407627/merge-two-rows-and-put-the-results-in-the-same-columns)

But now I would need to further split the results in the merge column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'List' : ['P111:P666', 'P999', 'P111;P999:P777 ','P555', 'P666:P111;P333'],
                    'Color' : ['R', 'R', 'B','Y', 'R']})

          List        Color
 0        P111:P666     R
 1             P999     R
 2  P111;P999:P777      B
 3             P555     Y
 4   P666:P111;P333     R


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cod' : ['P111', 'P222', 'P333', 'P444', 'P555', 'P666', 'P777'],
                    'Animal' : ['DOG,FROG', 'CAT', 'BUG','SNAKE,DOG', 'CAT,BUG', 'DOG', 'SNAKE']})
    Cod     Animal
0  P111   DOG,FROG
1  P222        CAT
2  P333        BUG
3  P444  SNAKE,DOG
4  P555    CAT,BUG
5  P666        DOG
6  P777      SNAKE
```

And I would like:

```
     List           Color     Animal             
 0  P111:P666           R     DOG,FROG:DOG      
 1  P999                R     -                  
 2  P111;P999:P777      B     DOG,FROG;-:SNAKE  
 3  P555                Y     CAT,BUG            
 4  P666:P111;P333      R     DOG:DOG,FROG;BUG
```

Basically I would like to put ";" and ":" in the "Animal" match column in accordance with the signs in the initial "List" column. If there isn't math I put "-"

Comment: I can see 'FROG' only in the desired result, is it missing and where does it come from?

Comment: You're right, I correct the question, forgive me for the oversight

Answer (score 0):

You can `split`, `explode`, then `merge` and aggregate again:

```
out = df1.join(
 df1['List']
 .str.split(';')
 .explode().reset_index(name='Cod')
 .merge(df2, how='left')
 .fillna('-')
 .groupby('index')
 .agg({'Animal': ':'.join,
       'Letter': '|'.join})
 )
```

Output:

```
             List   Color            Animal       Letter
0            P111     red          DOG,FROG          A,F
1            P999     red                 -            -
2  P111;P999;P777    blue  DOG,FROG:-:SNAKE    A,F|-|Z,L
3            P555  yellow           CAT,BUG          C,A
4  P666;P111;P333     red  DOG:DOG,FROG:BUG  M,C|A,F|S,M
```

##### keep separators

We need a different approach, using a regex:

```
regex = '|'.join(df2['Cod'])+'|\w+'
mapper = df2.set_index('Cod')['Animal'].to_dict()

df1['Animal'] = df1['List'].str.replace(regex, lambda x: mapper.get(x.group(), '-'), regex=True)
```

Output:

```
             List   Color            Animal
0            P111     red          DOG,FROG
1            P999     red                 -
2  P111;P999;P777    blue  DOG,FROG;-;SNAKE
3            P555  yellow           CAT,BUG
4  P666;P111;P333     red  DOG;DOG,FROG;BUG
```

Comment: this does not work because for example the line "P111;P999;P777    blue  DOG:-:SNAKE    A,F|-|Z,L" should instead be "P111;P999:P777    blue     DOG,FROG;-:SNAKE   A,F|-|Z,L" according to the signs on the initial list

Comment: The problem is to make the separators of the "List" column propagate on the "Animals" column

Comment: I see, then it probably needs a list of potential separators and a loop

Comment: Do you think it is very complex?

Comment: Maybe not but I'm on my phone and the screen is a bit tiny for that, maybe tomorrow (don't hesitate to remind me)

Comment: Would you have a moment for a check now?

Comment: I can't really resolve, sorry for insistence

Comment: See update for the mapping while keeping separators. Now you can combine both approaches (with only aggregation of the letters for the first part)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply and your time. However I don't think I understand it, now I just get ";" as a seperator?

Comment: Well then maybe there were too many infromations and it was confusing, could I take a quick look at you now? I need that in animals the elements are reported taking into account ":" and ";" initials in list