Extract data from dataframe based on list
I have a dataframe with several columns and many rows (few thousands), similar to this. One of the columns is a personal identifier number (PIN). Each PIN exist several times, with different values in the other columns. For each unique PIN, there are several LID that occurs many times, each with one result.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
     'PIN': [445588,445588,445588,668989,668989,212121], 
     'LID': [124, 124, 125, 625, 625, 325],    
     "Results": [8,5,3,23,11,45]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print (df)

I want to create a new dataframe for each unique PIN, but also count how many results there are for each unique LID. I am stuck on where to start. I have created a list with all the unique PIN, but how can I use this to search and create a new dataframe for each unique PIN?
patient_list = all_data['PIN'].tolist()
unique_list_patients = list(set(patient_list))
number_patients = len(unique_list_patients)

Should I use a for loop, or some sort of isin? I am very new to Python (coding in general) and find it difficult to know where to start.
For each unique PIN, I want to count how many unique LID, and also extract all data for each PIN into a new dataframe.

Your explanation is slightly confusing. To remove ambiguity, please show what your new DataFrame(s) should look like based on the data in your question

For each unique PIN, to get the count of unique LID values associated with each PIN you can use group by with the nunique() aggregate function like this:
new_df = df.groupby('PIN', as_index=False)['LID'].nunique()
print (new_df)

Results:
     PIN    LID
0  212121    1
1  445588    2
2  668989    1

if you want to keep the data from the original dataframe:
df['LID_Count'] = df.groupby('PIN')['LID'].transform('nunique')
print(df)

Results:
     PIN   LID  Results  LID_Count
0  445588  124        8          2
1  445588  124        5          2
2  445588  125        3          2
3  668989  625       23          1
4  668989  625       11          1
5  212121  325       45          1


here is a good reference for aggregation with pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas

Great thanks! Is there an easy way to also extract the data into separate dataframes that can be exported into excel sheets? I want to have a separate file for each unique PIN, if that makes sense?

Yes absolutely. To give you an answer I would need more information about your expected results but feel free to post another question about that issue. I also updated the answer with different results.

Basically I want to have separate exported excel files for each unique PIN. So one file for 445588 with all the columns from the original df, and then one file for 668989 and so on (there are hundreds of unique PIN and thousands of unique LID).

Post another question on stack overflow if you can. Also, if my answer helped you make sure to accept it

I think it will solve your problem....
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
 'PIN': [445588,445588,445588,668989,668989,212121], 
 'LID': [124, 124, 125, 625, 625, 325],    
 "Results": [8,5,3,23,11,45]
 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print (df)


grouped_df = df.groupby(['LID', 'PIN']).agg({'LID':'count']}).reset_index()

grouped_df.columns = [col[0] if col[-1] == '' else f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' for col in grouped_df.columns]

count = 0
with pd.ExcelWriter('file_name.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
 for i in range(len(grouped_df)):
      pin_tmp = grouped_df.iloc[count: count + 1]
      name = grouped_df.iloc[count: count + 1].iloc[0]['PIN'].astype(str)
      if name in writer.sheets:
        name = f"{name}_{count}"
      pin_tmp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
      count += 1

I'm using groupby and asking to count the recors. Last line of code I'm just joining dataframe column dimentions to create normal dataframe of one dimention column name.

Not sure I understand the last line of code. But the agg works fine! How can I extract the data for each of the unique PIN to a new dataframe (one for each PIN)?

try to see grouped_df after agg part. You will see a dataframe wit two level column name lines. So the last part of code just puts both column name level values to tuple and joins them to make one level column name.
I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put each pin to new dataframe, because if you will have 10k pins it will brake your memory. I updated my answer :)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
